# How to use onSignInChanged event handler in chrome extension for gmail?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

Here is the code of my google chrome extension

Manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
   "matches": [
   "https://mail.google.com/*",
   "https://inbox.google.com/*"
 ],
 "js": ["js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "js/content.js"],
 "css": ["css/custom.css"],
 "run_at": "document_end"
 }
],
"background":{
  "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
  "persistent": true
},
"permissions": [
  "https://mail.google.com/",
  "https://inbox.google.com/",
  "https://accounts.google.com/*",
  "identity",
  "identity.email",
  "storage"
],
"oauth2":{
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "scopes": [
    "profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
}
```

`background.js`

```
//get google OAuth Token
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
  interactive: true
}, function(token) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    return;
  }
  console.log(token);
  currentSessionAccessToken = token;
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  x.open('GET',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token
  );
  x.onload = function() {
    console.log(x.response);
  };
  x.send();
});

//registered event handler for signIn change
chrome.identity.onSignInChanged.addListener(function(accountInfo, isSignedIn){
  console.log(accountInfo);
});
```

But, **onSignInChanged** event is not fired when I switch to another user. Actually, I want to revoke the token generated for previously logged in user when signIn is changed and generate a new token for newly logged in user.

Since, the event is not fired, my extension is loading contacts of previously logged in user. I have followed Google's [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#event-onSignInChanged) documentation. No idea why the event is not getting fired. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Protip: don't create confusion by calling a persistent background page `eventpage`.

Comment: Just to be clear, define, step by step, "switch to another user" (by editing the question, not here in comments).

Comment: Thank you for the tip @Xan. I have made the edits.

Answer (score 0):

The event is not fired, however, a workaround is to check if currently logged in user and the email associated with the authentication token are same. If they are same then continue the application, if not, then revoke current token and generate a new one selecting the currently logged in user account. After that make the Google API request.

Comment: Hello. Did you get to solve the issue? If so,  could you please explain the steps?